# How do I escape the @ sign in Rythm?

Tags: java, template-engine, rythm

I am using Rythm (yup no h), a Java template engine.

The idea is to replace placeholders in a template file (e.g. a text file).

In my case I am dealing with JSON. To call the Rythm engine I only need to do:

```
Rythm.render("my @var1 content and my email is joe@acme  (or call @var2)", "foo", "bar");
```

The output is

```
[DEBUG] org.rythmengine.RythmEngine:69  - Rythm-1.1.1-    SNAPSHOT started in prod mode
my foo content and my email is joebar (or call )
[ INFO] org.rythmengine.RythmEngine:84  - Shutting down Rythm Engine: [re-wZ5]
```

As you can see the value `"bar"` went to @acme which the engine mistook for a placeholder. How can I escape the @ sign?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double the `@` to escape it:

`joe@acme` => `joe@@acme`

Checkout document at http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#at

### EDIT - Adding Sample Code

```
    System.out.println(Rythm.render("my @var1 content and my email is joe@@acme.com  (or call @var2)", "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"));
```

yields

```
[DEBUG]   org.rythmengine.RythmEngine:69  - Rythm-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT started in prod mode
my foo content and my email is joe@acme.com (or call bar)
[ INFO]   org.rythmengine.RythmEngine:84  - Shutting down Rythm Engine: [re-pI7]
```

Comment: I cannot believe I did not even think of that. Or maybe when I tried I made another mistake. Thanks!.